# Python 3 How to add specific lines from a list to an array

Tags: python, python-3.x

Below is my code. This code reads lines from a file (called compsc), strips the \n from them, puts them into an array and randomly prints them, eliminating each option that has already been printed. What I want to know is how to read only a specific set of lines into the array, as I will have lots of lines in the .txt file. So, is there some code that can do that, or do I have to put `readlines()` somewhere?
Thanks in advance!

```
import random
with open("compsc.txt", "r") as ins:
    qarray = []
    for line in ins:
        line = line.strip()
        qarray.append(line)
    print (qarray)
    loop = 0
    while loop != 4:
        newquestion = random.sample(qarray, 1)
        print (newquestion)
        qarray.remove(newcard[0])
        loop = loop + 1
```

Comment: what is the condition for specific set of lines into the array, ..just add that condition before appending

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will need to create some function to decide whether or not to keep the line.

```
import random

def line_filter(line):
    """Return True if you want to keep line, False otherwise."""
    ...

with open("compsc.txt", "r") as f:
    questions = [line.strip() for line in f if line_filter(line)]
    random.shuffle(questions)
    for question in questions[:4]:
        print(question)
```

Comment: Hello, thanks for the reply. What would I need to write in the `def line_filter(line):` to return a specific line to be true or false?

Comment: That's up to you. You seem to have some criteria to decide whether or not you want to print a line. You have to put those criteria in `line_filter`. If you want to keep the line, return `True`. Otherwise return `False`.

Comment: For example if you wanted to keep all lines containing the word "apple", you would put `return 'apple' in line`

Comment: I've been trying this, but I quickly realized that the program would only choose the top return, and ignore the others. For example: if `return 'apple' in line' was the first to go after the `def line_filter(line):' and then I would put `return 'pear' in line` python would only ever choose the string "apple", and anything below it (i.e. pear) would never get chosen.

Comment: If you have multiple conditions you'll have to combine them logically. Try `return 'apple' in line or 'pear' in line` or `return any(fruit in line for fruit in {'apple', 'pear', 'banana'})`

Answer (score 0):

This has been covered on this site before. In brief, if your file is not huge i.e. does not cause memory problems you could indeed use readlines. Also look into linecache, which is optimized.